# авторизация в vk.API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Не проходит авторизация

```
vkapi = vk.API(user_login='userlogin',user_password='userpass')
```

вызывает ошибку:

> vk.api.VkAuthorizationError: Authorization error (bad
>   password)

Пароль верный.Не так давно этот код проходил,но сейчас отказывается.

Answer (score 1):

Если заглянуть в [исходники библиотеки](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/master/vk/api.py), можно увидеть такую прелесть:

```
# Login
login_data = {
    'act': 'login',
    'utf8': '1',
    'email': self.user_login,
    'pass': self.user_password,
    'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
}

response = session.post('https://login.vk.com', login_data)
```

Так делать нельзя. Это не является официальным API, это может меняться когда угодно и как угодно. Что и произошло пару недель назад.

Наиболее правильным решением будет [открытие нормального диалога авторизации OAuth приложением в браузере](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile), но если это по каким-то причинам невозможно (а я ещё не знаю, как это в питоне вообще сделать :( ), то можно получить access_token вручную через браузер и использовать его при авторизации:

```
vkapi = vk.API(access_token='токен')
```

Comment: Можно использовать авторизацию для сайтов.
https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites

Comment: Но для серверной авторизации доступны далеко не все методы API.

Comment: @andreymeal да? а какие не доступны тогда?

Comment: Как минимум wall, что прямо написано в документации

Comment: wall.get, например, вообще не требует access_token. я не холивара ради, а для себя хочу разобраться. дайте ссылку, где написано об ограничениях, пожалуйста

Comment: http://vk.com/dev/permissions

Про wall написано прямым текстом, про другие методы не исключено, что «для Standalone-приложений» тоже означает недоступность с сервера, но лично не проверял.

Точно могу сказать, что wall.post с сервера недоступен, потому что я его использую с своём приложении.

Плюс в документации некоторых отдельных методов тоже написано, что они доступны только для Standalone-приложений, например http://vk.com/dev/groups.join

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25443/discussion-between-zzashpaupat-and-andreymal).